# Multiple Monitors One Screen Size is small

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I have 2 monitors attached to a laptop, running windows 7, and I am using the 3 as 3 seperate monitors the they each display different things, and for some reason one of the screans in smaller than its full display.While the other two are fine have full display.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Sorry for the delay note the screen size is not the actual screen size just same image.

[image]

I have resolved the issue yesterday but if someone gets the answer I will upvote it or if someone suggests something which is also valid.

Comment: It may be the resolution of the 3rd screen. Are they all the same resolution/size?

Comment: All different sizes

Comment: Currently its a bit speculation on what your problem is. Can you provide a screenshot or photo of what you see? You can upload it to imgurl or similar places and edit the link in your post, so someone with enough reputation will add it in your post.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I resolved the issue and had no time to post yesterday and I cant take a screenshot for security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution  under control panel display screen resolution to select the screen which was giving me the error and make this my current display and then the problem went away.

I had forgotten to select my main screen as my main display.